# Setting the Box's size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, border-layout

This may seem like a stupid question, but I would like to change the size of a 'box' in my jFrame.  I will include the code and a picture.

Here is the JTableResultSet class:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class JTableResultSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector columnNames = new Vector();
        Vector data = new Vector();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();   //
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/exper482_social", "admin", "testing");
            String sql = "Select username, forename, lastname, password from social_users";
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
                }
                data.addElement(row);
            }
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        TableColumn column;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setMaxWidth(250);//250
        }
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);        
        panel.add(scrollPane);       
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);//adding panel to the frame
        frame.setSize(600, 400); //setting frame size 600 400
        frame.setVisible(true);  //setting visibility true
    }
}
```

And here is the photo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wblfx.png

Can someone please tell me what i can do to make the box bigger? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BorderLayout` which will make the `JScrollPane` occupy the full area of the `JPanel`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

The default JPanel layout, `FlowLayout`, uses a component's preferred size which will not expand to fill the window.

Read [Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)